# Strange Runtime Error after obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, net-reactor

We have a assembly called **DataObjectJsonLoader**. Inside it there is an class as following:

```
 public static class DrillingFluidDataObjectJsonLoader
 {
     public static  Result<DrillingFluid> Load(string strDrillingFluid)
     {
        ....
        var type = ConvertToMudType(...);
        ....
     } 
     private static  MudType ConvertToMudType(string strDillingFluidType)
     {
      ....
     }     
 }
```

Everything works fine before obfuscation. The **obfuscator** we use is **Net Reactor 5.0**. And we already disable string encryption. But after obfuscation, when we call the above public function, there will be a runtime binder exception:

> the 'DrillingFluidDataObjectJsonLoader' does not contain a definition for 'ConvertToMudType'.

What is the root cause of this problem? 
And how to fix it?

Comment: Wouldn't Net Reactor support be the better place to ask this? Apparently it's renaming a private method, but not altering the call site.

Comment: Obfuscation and interpreted interfaces (almost all JSON tools do) is risky way. Are You sure, Your software will-be-by-someday-someone disassembled?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just exclude this class from obfuscation as a temporal solution...

```
  [Obfuscation(Exclude = true, ApplyToMembers = true)]
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, i wasnt aware of this attribute.